# i am n trying to use model values in my component to create a form

Tags: javascript, angular, model-view-controller, angular-reactive-forms

i am creating a reactive form in angular. i have a model which defines formLabel. i want to use its predefined type  and source values in form as a drop down menu

my models looks like this

```
export interface FormLabel {
  name?: string;
  type?: 'input' | 'input-h' | 'textarea' | 'slider' | 'select' | 'select-h' | 'multiselect' | 'multiselect-h' | 'date';
  created_by?: number;
  source: '1' | '2' | '1e' | '2m';
}
```

component form where i want to use this is

```
import {FormLabel} from '../../models/label';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit-attribute',
  templateUrl: './edit-attribute.component.html',
})
export class EditAttributeComponent implements OnInit {
  attributeEditForm: FormGroup


  constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditAttributeComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: FormLabel) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.attributeEditForm = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(this.data.name, Validators.required),
      'type': new FormControl(this.data.type),
      'source': new FormControl(this.data.data_source),
    });
  }
```

html file where i want to show value of type and source is

```
<form [formGroup]="attributeEditForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" id="1" formControlName="attribute_name">
    <input type="text" id="2" formControlName="attribute_type">
    <input type="text" id="3" formControlName="source">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>
```

Comment: You may need to clarify the relationship between the model you shared `FormLabel` and `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: AttributeLabel`. This data injected into the modal, is that an array of `FormLabel`? Have you tried using `ngFor*` to loop over each `FormLabel` to render the respective `input`? What have you tried exactly?

Comment: NOTE: ```formControlName``` should corrspond to the key defined in  ```formGroup```

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Ok sorry for not defining the whole situation so i am getting that data from a https service and its not an array it an object which looks like 
```
allowed_values: null
attribute_type: "input"
created_by: null
data_source: "P"
date_created: "2019-10-04T18:06:22.585000Z"
date_modified: "2019-10-04T18:06:22.585000Z"
default_value: null
display: false
hidden: true
hide_if_empty: false
id: 219
label: "enterprise"
max_length: null
min_length: null
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky i want to create a form based on the label Model so that fields like type and source can be created as dropdown or select and  use values defined in model .

Comment: Is an object with type `FormLabel` injected into `EditAttributeComponent`? How does model `FormLabel` related to `EditAttributeComponent` and `AttributeLabel` exactly? Or did you mean `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: FormLabel`?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky i am calling a function from a datagrid when a cell is clicked  at that time `data ` is getting passed to modal

`onCellClicked(event): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditAttributeComponent, {
      width: '100%',
      data: event.data,
      panelClass: 'custom-modalbox'
    }); 
`

Comment: What is the data type of the injected model? Is it `FormLabel` or is it `AttributeLabel`? If it's `AttributeLabel`? what does that model look like? Is one of it's properties `FormLabel`? Where exactly does `FormLabel` become available in `EditAttributeComponent`?

Comment: `AttribueLabel` is nothing `FormLabel` i forget to change it both are same

Comment: Please update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Not able to edit my code but it should be like 
`constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditAttributeComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: FormLabel) {}

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are trying to do with the `form` in terms of the input values. Can you please provide what a sample of actual data for `FormLabel` and what the final rendered `form` should look like? For example, if the data is `{ name: 'foo', type: 'select', created_by: 42, source: '1' }`, what would the form look like? Disregard Angular for a moment, just would would the form itself look like? Can you try to create a https://stackblitz.com/ to re-create your situation because there conflicts in your variable names, models, and template.